# Jackson deserialization feature which fails if not all properties are present?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's say I have this POJO:

```java
@Data
public class MyPojo {
  private boolean isEnabled;
  private int timeout;
}
```

Deserialization from JSON to the above POJO is done with Jackson 2.9. Now, additionally let's say a client sends an "invalid" request. In this context "invalid" means that one of the POJO  properties is null or empty. Here, `timeout` is missing.

```json
{
  "isEnabled": true
}
```

So far I could not find any Jackson deserialization feature which would make this case fail. Does Jackson provide something like "fail if not all properties are present"?

Answer (score 1):

This one won't work:

```
@JsonProperty(required = true)
```

You can use **constructor-based annotation** - it works as a workaround for this unimplemented Jackson feature:

```
@JsonCreator
public Foo(@JsonProperty(value = "val", required = true) int val) {
    this.val = val;
}
```